# Cannot invoke initializer for type 'posix_spawn_files_actions_t' with no arguments after installing Vapor/MySQL

Tags: mysql, swift, vapor

I keep getting the error `Cannot invoke initializer for type 'posix_spawn_files_actions_t' with no arguments` after installing Vapor/MySQL, prompted by this line of code in `Terminal.swift`: `var fileActions = posix_spawn_file_actions_t()`. Does anyone know what might prompt this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are compiling in Xcode, this is caused by Xcode targeting an iOS device. Change your run destination to 'My Mac'.